# Find what is the date format used by computer

Tags: batch-file, cmd, fortran

I have a batch script that uses "FORFILES". The problem with forfiles is that it uses local or region dependent data format. For example in India it will use a DD/MM/YYYY format while in Brazil it will use MM/DD/YYYY format.

My fortran code writes my batch script. Is there a way I can find what the date format being used is? I can use the answer to then create the date string as per the local setting.

Either a command line command or a fortran 77 code will solve my problem, but I cannot use any other language. ALso, I would prefer not installing a third party software for this.

Thanks

Comment: `mode con cp` tells you codepage.

Comment: I guess you could use `SYSTEM("date /T > file.txt")` and then read the file and see how the system has formatted the date.

Answer (score 2):

no clue about fortran, but in batch, you can get the date format with:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate') do set dateformat=%%a
```

(`%%a` in batch files, `%a` only on command line)

Comment: +1 as that is probably the easiest solution; I was trying to find a `wmic` query to get the format, but had no luck...